# How to update XmlNode attribute values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML file like this:

```
<caseData>   
  <entity type="case" name="1">
    <attribute name="CASE_OPEN" value="false"/>
    <attribute name="CASE_NUMBER" value=""/>
    <attribute name="CASE_TYPE" value=""/> 
  </entity> 
<caseData>
```

I need to update the value for the CASE_NUMBER and CASE_TYPE. The way I only can do is:

```
    _xd = new XmlDocument();
    _xd.LoadXml(xmlTemplate);
    var caseitem = _xd.GetElementsByTagName("entity")[0];
    var childnodes = caseitem.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode node in childnodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["name"].Value == "CASE_NUMBER")
                {
                    node.Attributes["value"].Value = "11222";
                }
                if (node.Attributes["name"].Value == "CASE_TYPE")
                {
                    node.Attributes["value"].Value = "NEW";
                }

            }
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using LINQ to XML. It's generally a nicer API to work with:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlTemplate);

var caseNumber = doc
    .Descendants("attribute")
    .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "CASE_NUMBER");

caseNumber.SetAttributeValue("value", "11222");
```

If this really is a template and you're just filling in the blanks, you can pretty easily just create it from scratch:

```
var attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"CASE_OPEN", "false"},
    {"CASE_NUMBER", "11122"},
    {"CASE_TYPE", "NEW"}
};

var caseData = new XElement("caseData",
    new XElement("entity",
        new XAttribute("type", "case"),
        new XAttribute("name", "1"),
        AttributeElements(attributes)
    )
);
```

Where `AttributeElements` is something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> AttributeElements(
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> attributes)
{
    return attributes.Select(x => new XElement("attribute",
        new XAttribute("name", x.Key),
        new XAttribute("value", x.Value)
    ));
}
```